# How to send SOAP request to WSO2 ELB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I wanto to send SOAP request to ESB thru ELB. What is it required to be done?
when I send directly to the port of ELB I get connection refused/No dynamicloadbalanceendpoint application member not available. Or should I run it as admin?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuration for WSO2 ELB with WSO2 ESB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158973/configuration-for-wso2-elb-with-wso2-esb)