# Configuration for WSO2 ELB with WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want configuration files for WSO2 ELB 2.1.1 and WSO2 ESB 4.8.1, axis2.xml loadbalancer.config carbon.xml catalina-server.xml and any other if there.
I have configured with one ELB(offset 0, 8280), one manager(offset 1, 8281) and one worker(offset 2, 8282) ESB and when i try to send a request via ELB I'm getting

> DynamicLoadbalanceEndpoint application member not available

but both are available and get the log that mgt and worker have joined when they turn on in ELB. 

Initially when i send a request i have got

> httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect

then I have set allowall in axis2.xml and got the error which I have mentioned.
What would be the problem? If someone who have already configured could share the configuration files it will be very helpful for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [WSO2 Clustering and Deployment Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/WSO2+Clustering+and+Deployment+Guide). There are instructions to [configure an ESB cluster](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+ESB).

If the ESB cluster is not connected to the ELB, you will see "application member not available" message in ELB logs when you try to send requests.

Comment: ESB and ELB are in cluster, when the esb server is started I'm getting logs in ELB that this ESB is joined in the cluster as manager or worker.

Comment: There must be some configuration issue or you might be using wrong hostname. Please note that you need to use the correct hostname for ESB cluster and make sure that hostname is mapped to the ELB. ELB identifies the correct service cluster by the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful to someone else in future:

The WSO2 Elastic Load Balancer has been discontinued as of July 1st 2015. You can download NGinx Plus [[1]](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/) - the load balancer by NGinx - for which we provide support.